# Sorting by month in PHP

Tags: php, sorting

please forgive any unclear thoughts, as this is all new to me. I have a custom built cms to control a few small things on my website. I did not build this cms so I looked through the files to see how things were working and I seem to be stuck on one issue. I have an events page that lists out events input through the cms. It does a fine job of sorting the events out by the current month, but when you click "next month" all it does is refresh the page and change the url to "events.php?next_month=2" - all while keeping only the current months events up still. Could anyone take a look at this and point me in the right direction? Any advice would help majorly, as I do not work with these languages generally. Thanks!!

Here's the code pulling in the events and making the month changing bar:

```
<div id="show">
          <ul id="months">
            <li class="show">Show:</li>
            <li class="active"><a href="events.php">This Month</a></li>
            <?php 
                $nextmonth=date("m") + 1;
                if($nextmonth > 12){
                    $nextmonth=1;
                }
            ?>
            <li><a href="events.php?next_month=<?php echo $nextmonth;?>" >Next Month</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Annual events</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <!--div show-->

<?php if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
    while($obj=mysql_fetch_object($result)){

        if(date("m", strtotime($obj->eventDate)) == date("m")){
            $class="";
        }
        else{
        $class="style='display:none;'";
        }
        ?>
        <div <?php echo $class;?>>
          <ul class="show_detail1">
            <li class="month_img">
              <label><?php echo date("F", strtotime($obj->eventDate));?> <strong><?php echo date("d", strtotime($obj->eventDate));?></strong></label>
              <?php


?>
            </li>
            <li>
              <h4><img src="images/event_img4.png" alt="" /> where</h4>
              <p><span><?php echo $obj->location;?></span> <?php echo $obj->city.", ".$obj->state;?><br />
                <br />
                <?php echo $obj->phone;?><br />
                <br />
                <a href="<?php echo $obj->website;?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $obj->website;?></a></p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <h4><img src="images/event_img5.png" alt="" />when</h4>
              <p>
                <?php   echo date("F jS, Y", strtotime($obj->eventDate));?>
                <br />
                <?php if($obj->eventStartTime && $obj->eventEndTime){ 
              echo $obj->eventStartTime." - ".$obj->eventEndTime;
              } else {
                  echo "Time TBD"; }?>
              </p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <h4><img src="images/event_img6.png" alt="" />what?</h4>
              <p><?php echo $obj->eventTitle;?><BR />
              </p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

            <?php }


         } ?>
```

Apologies if i'm missing a closing div, it was a quick copy/paste. Thank you again very much, any help or direction will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Where is the query? Where is the logic?

Comment: I'm not sure, this is not my code and I don't really work with php :(.   Is there something else I can provide to help? I know where all the classes and such are.

Comment: Well, if it were just this little page of coding, we'd be able to shed a light on what could be causing the error(s). But seeing as we don't know how/where all the variables are set and/or where all the functions are going, we can't help you out here.